# override function plugin woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use the [discounts for woocommerce subscriptions](https://woocommerce.com/products/discounts-for-woocommerce-subscriptions/) plugin

I want to make a change in one of the functions, but I don't know how to do it

Direction : /plugins/discounts-for-woocommerce-subscriptions/src/Entity/DiscountedOrderItem.php

```
<?php namespace MeowCrew\SubscriptionsDiscounts\Entity;

use Exception;
use MeowCrew\SubscriptionsDiscounts\DiscountsManager;
use WC_Order_Item_Product;
use WC_Subscription;

class DiscountedOrderItem {

    /**
     * Order Item
     *
     * @var WC_Order_Item_Product
     */
    private $item;

    /**
     * Subscription
     *
     * @var WC_Subscription
     */
    private $subscription;

    /**
     * DiscountedOrderItem constructor.
     *
     * @param WC_Order_Item_Product $item
     * @param WC_Subscription|null $subscription
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function __construct( WC_Order_Item_Product $item, WC_Subscription $subscription = null ) {
        $this->item = $item;

        $subscription = $subscription ? $subscription : false;

        if ( ! $subscription ) {
            $order = $this->getItem()->get_order();

            if ( $order ) {
                $subscription = wcs_get_subscription( $order->get_id() );
            }
        }

        if ( $subscription ) {
            $this->subscription = $subscription;
        } else {
            throw new Exception( 'Invalid order item' );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get subscription from item
     *
     * @return WC_Subscription
     */
    public function getSubscription() {
        return $this->subscription;
    }

    /**
     * Get order item from DiscountedItem
     *
     * @return WC_Order_Item_Product
     */
    public function getItem() {
        return $this->item;
    }

    public function getDiscounts() {
        return array_filter( (array) $this->getItem()->get_meta( '_dfws_discounts' ) );
    }

    public function getDiscountsType() {
        return (string) $this->getItem()->get_meta( '_dfws_type' );
    }

    public function getAppliedDiscount() {
        $appliedDiscount = (int) $this->getItem()->get_meta( '_dfws_applied_discount' );

        if ( $appliedDiscount < 1 ) {
            return false;
        }

        return $appliedDiscount;
    }

    public function updateAppliedDiscount( $key ) {
        if ( array_key_exists( $key, $this->getDiscounts() ) ) {
            $this->getItem()->update_meta_data( '_dfws_applied_discount', $key );
            $this->getItem()->save();
        }
    }

    public function isDiscountedItem() {
        return ! empty( $this->getDiscounts() );
    }

    public function getTotalRenewals() {
        $total = $this->getSubscription()->get_payment_count();

        // Do not take into account trial order as renewal
        if ( $this->getSubscription()->get_trial_period() ) {
            $total --;
        }

        return $total;
    }

    public function calculateAppliedDiscount( $totalRenewals = null ) {
        $totalRenewals   = $totalRenewals ? $totalRenewals : $this->getTotalRenewals();
        $appliedDiscount = false;

        foreach ( $this->getDiscounts() as $number => $discount ) {
            if ( $totalRenewals >= $number ) {
                $appliedDiscount = $number;
            }
        }

        return $appliedDiscount;
    }

    public function applyNewDiscount( $newDiscount ) {
        $discounts = $this->getDiscounts();

        $oldDiscount = $this->getAppliedDiscount();

        if ( array_key_exists( $newDiscount, $discounts ) && $oldDiscount !== $newDiscount ) {

            $newDiscountAmount = $discounts[ $newDiscount ];

            if ( $this->getDiscountsType() === 'percentage' ) {
                $originalPrice = $this->getOriginalPrice();
                $newPrice      = $originalPrice - ( ( $originalPrice / 100 ) * $newDiscountAmount );
            } else {
                $newPrice = $newDiscountAmount;
            }

            $newPrice = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $this->getItem()->get_product(), array(
                'price' => $newPrice,
            ) );

            $this->updateAppliedDiscount( $newDiscount );

            $this->getItem()->set_total( $newPrice * $this->getItem()->get_quantity() );
            $this->getItem()->calculate_taxes();

            $this->getSubscription()->calculate_totals();

            $this->getItem()->save();
            $this->getSubscription()->save();

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function getOriginalPrice() {
        return (float) $this->getItem()->get_product()->get_price();
    }

    public static function getPercentageDiscountBetweenPrices( $price, $salePrice ) {

        if ( $price <= 0 && $salePrice <= 0 ) {
            return null;
        }

        if ( $salePrice > $price ) {
            return ceil( 100 * $salePrice / $price );
        }

        return ceil( 100 - ( $salePrice * 100 / $price ) );
    }

    public static function formatRenewalNumber( $number ) {

        if ( $number < 1 ) {
            return 0;
        }

        switch ( $number ) {
            case 1:
                $renewalNumber = $number . 'st';
                break;
            case 2:
                $renewalNumber = $number . 'nd';
                break;
            case 3:
                $renewalNumber = $number . 'rd';
                break;
            default:
                $renewalNumber = $number . 'th';
        }

        return $renewalNumber;
    }

    public static function addDiscounts( WC_Order_Item_Product $item ) {
        $productId = $item->get_variation_id() ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();
        $discounts = DiscountsManager::getDiscounts( $productId );

        if ( ! empty( $discounts ) ) {

            $discountsType = DiscountsManager::getDiscountsType( $productId );

            try {
                $item->add_meta_data( '_dfws_discounts', $discounts, true );
                $item->add_meta_data( '_dfws_type', $discountsType, true );
                $item->add_meta_data( '_dfws_applied_discount', 0, true );
            } catch ( Exception $e ) {
                return;
            }

            $item->save();
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to change the following function :

```
public function getOriginalPrice() {
    return (float) $this->getItem()->get_product()->get_price();
}
```

I did not see a hook, how to rewrite the above function?

```
return (float) $this->getItem()->get_product()->get_regular_price();
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Object Oriented Programming. You what want to change is not a function but rather a Method that exists in a Class.

You can extend the `DiscountedOrderItem` Class to override the method. Here's the basic syntax:

```
class ParentClass {
    public function test($param) {
        return "\n Parent - the parameter value is $param";
    }
}
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public function test($param) {
        echo "\n Child - the parameter value is $param";
    }
}
$objParentClass = new ParentClass;
$objChildClass = new ChildClass;
$objParentClass->test('class ParentClass');
$objChildClass->test('class ChildClass');
```

Source: https://medium.com/oceanize-geeks/phps-method-overriding-1de659caaa43